# How to create a specific lighting in 3D graphics for a disk?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color, textures, lighting

I am trying to get a 3D disk with gradient lighting that is darker at the center and gradually goes white at the edges. I managed to get the correct lighting but could not make it a circular shape instead of a rectangle.

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Opacity[0.6], 
  Texture[RadialGradientImage[{Red, White}]], 
  Polygon[{{-6.2, -6.2, 1.1}, {6.2, -6.2, 1.1}, {6.2, 6.2, 
     1.1}, {-6.2, 6.2, 1.1}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
 Lighting -> {"Spot", White}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
cf[x_] := Blend[{Red, White}, x];
RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && -0.02 < z < 0.02
 , {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}
 , Mesh -> {0, 0, 1}
 , MeshStyle -> Directive @@ {Thick, Lighter@Pink}
 , ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, cf[(x^2 + y^2)^(1/5)]]
 , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
 , MaxRecursion -> 4
 , PlotPoints -> 80
 , Lighting -> {"Spot", White}
 , Boxed -> False
 , Axes -> False
 , SphericalRegion -> True
 , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]
 ]
```

[image]

---

*Notes*

1. Actual on-screen resolution is better than shown in the gif file above.
2. The ring at the boundary can be removed by commenting out the `Mesh` commands.
3. More `PlotPoints` are required to display thinner disks properly.

Comment: How to record the animation of turning the plot object to gif?@Syed

Comment: I use [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/). @metroidman

Answer (score 7):

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 {u Sin[Pi/2] Cos[v], u Sin[Pi/2] Sin[v], u Cos[Pi/2]}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
 Axes -> False,
 Boxed -> False,
 Lighting -> AmbientLight[White],
 Mesh -> None,
 PlotPoints -> 60,
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &),
 PlotStyle -> Texture[RadialGradientImage[{Red, White}]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[
 Norm[{x, y, z}], {"ZStackedPlanes", 1}, {x, y, z} ∈ Ball[], 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, Blend[{Red, White}, .8]}, #1] &)]
```

[image]